# Datanitro failed to find Python

Tags: datanitro

I have previously used Datanitro with Python 2.7. Now after a break when I have probably forgotten half of what I knew, I thought I would start to use Python 3.

Python 3.5.2 is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\
In DataNitro settings, I have unticked "Use default Python" and entered above path in "Use a custom Python directory". The same directory is also in path in environment variables. In case it is relevant I have also unticked "Use IPython" in DataNitro settings.

When I try to run even one of the sample DataNitro scripts I get the error "DataNitro failed to find Python. Please install cPython >= 2.6 and set correct path in DataNitro settings"

I am on Windows 10.

Any thoughts on what is still wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug we recently fixed. Please try downloading the newest version and see if that resolves the error.

Source: I'm one of the developers.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I did that and it worked. I had assumed I had the latest version as the last update shown on your website is 1/2/15.